# ¿Cómo poner imágenes fijas al pulsar una tecla para representar disparos?

Tags: python, python-3.x, imagen, pygame, animación

estoy intentando hacer que en PyGame se muestre una imagen con `blit` cuando pulse una tecla y que esta imagen se mantenga, es decir que se quede mostrada en la pantalla hasta nueva orden.

He conseguido que aparezca y desaparezca la imagen mientras presiono la tecla con `pygame.key.get_pressed`, pero eso no me sirve en este caso.

Si no tengo mal entendido, con `key.get_pressed` lo único que hace es obtener la pulsación de la tecla y sólo muestra la imagen mientras la mantengas presionada.

Así es cómo lo estoy intentando sin el `get_pressed`.

```
if [pygame.K_SPACE]:
       PANTALLA.blit(imagen, (850, 25))
```

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Si vuelves a pulsar la misma tecla ¿que debe ocurrir? ¿se quita la imagen?¿nada?¿se agrega otra?

Comment: Nada, es para añadir disparos, quiero que al pulsar la tecla, aparezca y luego ya me apañaré de hacer el movimiento hasta que salga de la pantalla por ejemplo. Por lo tanto, que se quede fija solo con pulsar una vez y luego no ocurra nada.

Comment: A vale, sería un "proyectil" entonces. ¿No quieres poder disparar repetidamente, es decir, poder tener varios proyectiles pululando por ahí simultáneamente? Por otro lado ¿quieres o puedes usar POO, lo digo por usar una clase que derive de `pygame.sprite.Sprite` para representar el sprite, facilitaría las cosas.

Comment: Pues me interesaría saber cómo, pues sí, justamente es lo que quiero, poder disparar varios proyectiles, todavía no se mucho de POO. ¿Sería entonces crear una clase para el proyectil y que cuando pulse la tecla haga lo especificado en la clase o como sería?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El uso de `get_pressed` es correcto, pero debes almacenar las imágenes/sprites en algún contenedor y en cada iteración del ciclo principal volver a calcular la posición para cada una y redibujarla hasta que salgan de la pantalla, colisionen o lo que sea.

La forma apropiada, más simple y escalable creo que es:

- Para cada sprite creamos una clase que derive de [`pygame.sprite.Sprite`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) o de alguna de sus subclases. En ella implementaremos toda las características y atributos del objeto, vida, armas, velocidad, etc así como todas las acciones que dicho sprite puede realizar, desde dispara, a morir, explotar, etc.
- Agrupamos los sprites en un grupo o grupos de sprites, usando `pygame.sprite.Group()`. Los grupos nos permiten actualizar y dibujar todos los sprites que contienen de forma simple y eficiente sin tener que iterar sobre los objetos.

Un ejemplo completo:

```
import time
import pygame as pg
from pygame.locals import K_DOWN, K_UP, K_RIGHT, K_LEFT, K_SPACE, K_b, QUIT
from pygame.math import Vector2


SCREEM_WIDTH = 1280
SCREEM_HEIGHT = 720


class StarShip(pg.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, posicion=(0, 0)):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pg.transform.scale(
            pg.image.load("assets/starshipdark.png") , (200, 200)
            )
        self.img = self.image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=posicion)
        self.posicion = Vector2(posicion)
        self.velocidad = Vector2(0,  0)
        self.x_vel = Vector2(0,  7)
        self.y_vel = Vector2(4,  0)

        self.cadencia_torpedo = 1
        self.cadencia_laser = 0.4

        self.proyectiles = pg.sprite.Group()

        self._t_ultimo_laser = time.time()
        self._t_ultimo_torpedo = time.time()


    def update(self):
        keys = pg.key.get_pressed()
        self.velocidad = (0,  0)
        if keys[K_UP]:
            self.velocidad += -self.x_vel
        if keys[K_DOWN]:
            self.velocidad += self.x_vel
        if keys[K_LEFT]:
            self.velocidad += -self.y_vel
        if keys[K_RIGHT]:
            self.velocidad += self.y_vel
        if keys[K_SPACE]:
            now_time = time.time()
            if now_time - self._t_ultimo_laser >= self.cadencia_laser:
                self._t_ultimo_laser = now_time
                self.proyectiles.add(
                    Laser(Vector2(self.rect.x + 35,  self.rect.y + 110)), 
                    Laser(Vector2(self.rect.x + 62,  self.rect.y + 95)), 
                    Laser(Vector2(self.rect.x + 137,  self.rect.y + 95)), 
                    Laser(Vector2(self.rect.x + 160,  self.rect.y + 110))
                    )
        if keys[K_b]:
            now_time = time.time()
            if now_time - self._t_ultimo_torpedo >= self.cadencia_torpedo:
                self._t_ultimo_torpedo = now_time
                self.proyectiles.add(
                    Torpedo(Vector2(self.rect.center))
                    )
        self.posicion +=  self.velocidad
        self.rect.center = self.posicion
        self.proyectiles.update()


class Torpedo(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, posicion):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pg.transform.scale(
               pg.image.load("assets/torpedo.png") , (60, 60)
               )
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = posicion
        self.posicion = posicion
        self.velocidad = Vector2(0,  -10)    

    def update(self):
        self.posicion += self.velocidad
        self.rect.center = self.posicion
        # Destruir cuando se salga de la ventana (superior)
        if self.rect.bottom < 0:    
            self.kill()   

class Laser(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, posicion):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pg.transform.scale(
               pg.image.load("assets/laser.png") , (60, 60)
               )
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = posicion
        self.posicion = posicion
        self.velocidad = Vector2(0,  -15)    

    def update(self):
        self.posicion += self.velocidad
        self.rect.center = self.posicion
        # Destruir cuando se salga de la ventana (superior)
        if self.rect.bottom < 0:    
            self.kill()   

def main():
    pg.init()
    ventana = pg.display.set_mode((SCREEM_WIDTH, SCREEM_HEIGHT))

    star_ship = StarShip((SCREEM_WIDTH / 2, SCREEM_HEIGHT / 2))
    star_ship_grp = pg.sprite.GroupSingle(star_ship)

    clock = pg.time.Clock()
    while True:
        clock.tick(60)
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                break
        star_ship_grp.update()
        ventana.fill((0,  0,  0))
        star_ship.proyectiles.draw(ventana)
        star_ship_grp.draw(ventana)

        pg.display.flip()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    pg.quit()
```

### Assets

Provienen los tres de [opengameart.org](https://opengameart.org/content/space-starter-kit) y son de dominio público:

[image: assets/starshipdark.png]
[image: assets/torpedo.png]
[image: assets/laser.png]

### Resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Woow qué respuesta más completa, ya voy entendiendo. Voy a revisar con calma todo el código que me has pasado. Muchísimas gracias, me has salvado la vida :D

Comment: Hola, si al revisar tienes cualquier duda sobre el código comenta, no he explicado todo de forma pormenorizada aunque si he intentado dar nombres descriptivos a cada variable y agregar algunos comentarios al código. Si no consigues deducir que hace algo o tienes dudas por ejemplo el uso de Vector2 comenta e intento explicarlo lo mejor que pueda. Saludos.

Comment: Estupendo, ¡qué máquina! Saludos.

Comment: Hola, llevo todos estos días revisando línea por línea y entiendo bastante, pero me cuesta. Gracias a lo que me enviaste, he conseguido que el personaje dispare (no es una nave). Tengo las animaciones de los movimientos en listas con diferentes png y en mi juego original (el que el personaje no podía disparar) se mueve correctamente, pero no consigo adaptar tu código al mío o el mío al tuyo. La cuestión es ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que se mueva la animación al pulsar una tecla?

Comment: Tengo esto en la clase del personaje: